# Automapper attempts to create object when map returns null

Tags: c#, automapper

When I try to do some custom mapping and sometimes map a destination property to null, Automapper throws an exception trying to create the destination property object.

I've uploaded a simplified project to github to demonstrate:
https://github.com/dreing1130/AutoMapper_Investigation

This began when I upgraded from Automapper 6 to 8.

If I return a newed up object instead of null it works fine (my application is expecting that value to be null in these cases though)

I also confirmed that a breakpoint inside my map is hit each time the mapping is called to make sure there wasn't a compiled execution plan

```
public class Source
{
    public IEnumerable<string> DropDownValues { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public SelectList DropDown { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForMember(d => d.DropDown, o => o.MapFrom((src, d) =>
        {
            return src.DropDownValues != null
                ? new SelectList(src.DropDownValues,
                    src.SelectedValue)
                : null;
        }));
```

Expected Result: Destination.DropDown is null when Source.DropdownValues is null

Actual Result: An Exception is thrown

"System.Web.Mvc.SelectList needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.Parameter name: type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`PreCondition`](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions) here, which will avoid mapping (and even trying to resolve the source value) if the specified condition is not met:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.DropDown, o =>
    {
        o.PreCondition(src => src.DropDownValues != null);
        o.MapFrom((src, d) =>
        {
            return new SelectList(src.DropDownValues, src.SelectedValue);
        });
    });
```

The reason for needing this is explained [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#resolvers-and-conditions):

> For each property mapping, AutoMapper attempts to resolve the
>   destination value before evaluating the condition. So it needs to be
>   able to do that without throwing an exception even if the condition
>   will prevent the resulting value from being used.